# PWA on iOS – install prompt icon

Tags: ios, icons, progressive-web-apps

I can't figure out which icon dimensions I need to use for the install to home screen prompt for a PWA. For now, the icon next to the PWA's name has a white border. Twitter for instance managed to have a full-bleed icon.

So far I tried:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="192x192" href="assets/icons/apple-touch-icon-192x192.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="assets/icons/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png">
        
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="assets/icons/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="assets/icons/favicon-16x16.png">
// and a manifest
<link rel="manifest" href="assets/icons/site.webmanifest">
```

Thanks for any input!

[image: PWA prompt]

[image: PWA prompt twitter]

Answer (score 2):

Documentation: https://web.dev/install-criteria/

this shows 192x192 and 512x512 px.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look!

Answer (score 2):

I have the following icons in my application:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="images/ios/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="images/ios/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="images/ios/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="images/ios/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="images/ios/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="images/ios/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="images/ios/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="images/ios/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="512x512" href="images/ios/apple-touch-icon-512x512.png" />
```

This will cover different iPhone screen sizes, I have tried in iPhone 6, XS and 12 and I get the same result.

You can use this website to generate most of them: https://favicomatic.com/

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that! And thanks for the link!